# ¿Como hacer una lfuncion recursiva en haskell que verifique que, para los indices pares, los valores cumplen una condicion par?

Tags: haskell

estoy teniendo un inconveniente con un ejercicio. La consigna del mismo es:
**"Dado un contingente, queremos saber si los que están en la posición par tienen todos un
scoring par. Debe funcionar para un contingente de personas par o impar."**

Un contingente en este caso es una lista de data Persona. La funcion scoringPar se definio de esta manera:

```
puntosDeScoring persona | (tieneAmigosPares.amigosPersona) persona && (tieneAmigos.amigosPersona) persona = nivelStress persona * edadPersona persona
                        | edadPersona persona > 40 = (length.amigosPersona) persona * edadPersona persona
                        | otherwise = calculoLetrasDelNombre cantidadDeLetrasDelNombrePorDos persona
```

Definí la función de la consigna de esta manera:

```
scoringParContingente (persona:personas) indice | even indice && even(puntosDeScoring persona) = scoringParContingente personas (indice + 1)
                                                | even indice = False
                                                | otherwise = scoringParContingente personas (indice + 1)
```

Y el error que obtengo en consola es el siguiente:

```
*Main> scoringParContingente contingenteTocTrue 4
*** Exception: correcionDelTPFuncionalC2-2022.hs:(293,1)-(295,105): Non-exhaustive patterns in function scoringParContingente

*Main> scoringParContingente contingenteTocFalse 3
False
*Main> scoringParContingente contingenteTocFalse 4
False
*Main> scoringParContingente contingenteTocTrue 5 
False
```

Probando con un contingente que da True el resultado me tira dicha excepcion y con uno que debe dar False da false.

¿Podrían comentarme que es en lo que estoy fallando?

Saludos

Answer (score 0):

El error *"Non-exhaustive patterns in function `scoringParContingente`"* ocurre cuando hay casos que no están considerados por el patrón de búsquedas. Si lo piensas bien, la función retorna un booleano, pero el único retorno booleano explícito es `False`. ¿Cómo se supone que retorna `True`?¿En qué caso?

Un caso que no tienes en cuenta es cuando la lista está vacía. Si en cada iteracción reduces la lista, alguna vez llegará a estar vacía. Si usas algún IDE que tenga el HLS (*Haskell Language Server*), te advierte enseguida que no has cubierto todos los casos.

Se podría reescribir así:

```hs
scoringParContingente [] _ = True
scoringParContingente (persona:personas) indice
  | even indice = even (puntosDeScoring persona) && scoringParContingente personas (indice + 1)
  | otherwise = scoringParContingente personas (indice + 1)
```

Pero en un lenguaje funcional hay un modo mejor de hacer las cosas sin usar recursividad. La lista `personas` la puedes combinar mediante `zip` y ver si se cumple la condición:

```hs
scoringParContingente personas = and [even (puntosDeScoring persona) | (persona, indice) <- zip personas [1..], even indice]
```

Alternativamente:

```hs
scoringParContingente personas = all even [puntosDeScoring persona | (persona, indice) <- zip personas [1..], even indice]
```

Comment: Muchas gracias por la data. LO tendré en cuenta para estos casos.